# How to turn a list of byte-strings into a string in Python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have this, via the Github API, after base64 decoding:

```
[b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n', b'<html>\n', b'    <head>\n']
```

And I'd really like a string (with `\n` line endings), or a list of strings.

I spent an hour chasing `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` because I thought it was **already** a list of strings, and questioning my own lambda/filter skills before I realized the root cause was somewhere else. I tried googling but I only get hits for 'python bytes to string' which is different.

Comment: How is "python bytes to string" different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just `map` the `bytes.decode` method to each element and then `join` it if you need a single string:

```
l = [b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n', b'<html>\n', b'    <head>\n']
s = "".join(map(bytes.decode, l))
```

or, call `decode` on each element in a list-comp if you need a list:

```
ls = [i.decode() for i in l]
```

With the results now being:

```
>>> print(repr(s))  # repr to show \n 
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <head>\n'
>>> print(ls)
['<!DOCTYPE html>\n', '<html>\n', '    <head>\n']
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't help but wonder if the error message for `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not str` could be more helpful for noobs

Comment: Thanks for your great help. I was working on something cmd & tkinter. So I need these help.